# Allow support to kill a running process (SDDL/ACE)

Tags: windows, process

In our work environment, we have a lower level support group that is responsible for handling routine problems and maintenance.  One problem is being able to allow them to recycle certain high(er) level services, and kill high(er) level processes.

Allowing them to stop, pause, and start services can be obtained by setting the SDDL/ACE via the SC command, something I just recently figured out how to do (woo hoo).  But i haven't yet figured out how to allow them to stop a process that is running.

In our environment we have some vendor services that will spawn another running process (serviceA.exe spawns processB.exe).  Occasionally that process may go haywire and it needs to be killed, otherwise problems will ensue.  What can I use to view and set the sddl/ace so a certain AD security group will be allowed to kill that second process?   What is that ACE code that would allow it?

Comment: I suppose you could create another service on that same machine that does a `TASKKILL /F /IM "processname"` and allow them to start that service but ensure on configuration it's set to a manual start up type?

Comment: i did realize that i can use accesschk,exe from sysinternals to find various permissions of running processes.  So that is at least something.

Comment: I'm not sure how complex your process is but if it runs as `LOCAL SYSTEM` when you configure the service then you can create another service that also runs as `LOCAL SYSTEM` but set to it start manual only and then code it to execute the OS TASKKILL command for the EXE name of the process. If you're users have access to start services remotely, etc. from services.msc, then just have then start the new process that will ONLY kill the process name with TASKKILL and then stop running... That was just a quick thought but I'm not sure how you have everything configured on your setup.